# Is it possible to use Unsafe.CompareAndSwap with a memory position rather an offset with an object?

Tags: java

Most of the Unsafe operations accept a memory position in order to perform the operation - for example:

```
    Unsafe unsafe = Context.unsafe;
    long position = unsafe.allocateMemory(8);
    unsafe.putLong(position, 0);
```

However, the CAS operations as far a I can see do not offer this - they instead take an Object as one of the arguments:

```
    unsafe.compareAndSwapLong(this, offset, expected, newvalue)
```

However, given the long which is at the position "position", how can I perform a CAS operation without it being a field within an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of [Unsafe.getInt(Object o, long offset)](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.html#getInt%28Object,%20long%29):

> Fetches a value from a given Java variable.
>   More specifically, fetches a field or array element within the given
>   object o at the given offset, or (if o is
>   null) from the memory address whose numerical value is the given
>   offset.

Possibly (I haven't personally tested this) the same applies to `compareAndSwapLong`, so you could try passing `null` in for `o` and make `offset` a memory address.

---

Digging into the native code, comparing `compareAndSwapLong`'s [code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/4fc084dac61e/src/share/vm/prims/unsafe.cpp#l1107):

```
UNSAFE_ENTRY(jboolean, Unsafe_CompareAndSwapLong(JNIEnv *env, jobject unsafe, jobject obj, jlong offset, jlong e, jlong x))

UnsafeWrapper("Unsafe_CompareAndSwapLong");
  Handle p (THREAD, JNIHandles::resolve(obj));
  jlong* addr = (jlong*)(index_oop_from_field_offset_long(p(), offset));
  ...
```

and `getInt`'s [code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/4fc084dac61e/src/share/vm/prims/unsafe.cpp#l147):

```
#define GET_FIELD(obj, offset, type_name, v) \
  oop p = JNIHandles::resolve(obj); \
  type_name v = *(type_name*)index_oop_from_field_offset_long(p, offset)
```

---

both use `JNIHandles::resolve(obj)` so they probably use the same null-object-handling logic.

Comment: Interesting, I'm going to need to do some more experimentation it seems - I originally thought this was the issue because Unsafe.CompareAndSwapLong was consistently returning false (using null as you have suggested). I'll give it another chance later.

Comment: This worked, I was being a moron and accidentally changing the memory position before doing it (functions with similar names)